# Android OS shuts down - Error reporting WTF

Tags: android, logcat, fatal-error

i had my application working fine for hours then out of the blue I got this message and the phone shuts down:

```
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188): Error reporting WTF
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188): android.os.DeadObjectException
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationWtf(ActivityManagerNative.java:3287)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.wtf(RuntimeInit.java:331)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.util.Log$1.onTerribleFailure(Log.java:105)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:359)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.util.Log.wtf(Log.java:336)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.finalize(PowerManager.java:414)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:186)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:169)
    07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-04 16:39:01.974: E/AndroidRuntime(12188): --------- beginning of /dev/log/main
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188): android.os.DeadObjectException
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.getBluetoothState(IBluetooth.java:1297)
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getState(BluetoothAdapter.java:476)
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering(BluetoothAdapter.java:852)
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at com.vittorio.floaty.ScannerManager.run(ScannerManager.java:43)
07-04 16:39:02.089: E/BluetoothAdapter(12188):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Repeated for maybe 500 lines inside the logcat. I have no idea what's that about also because my application looks like is not involved and was not doing anything when the fatal error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

DeadObjectException is thrown when:

> The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no
>   longer exists.

Are you binding to a service in your app?
The docs say:

> You should always trap DeadObjectException exceptions, which are
>   thrown when the connection has broken. This is the only exception
>   thrown by remote methods.

In this particular context, the "connection" refers to the service connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No I'm not using any service in my app and ,based on what you said, in my case the object I'm making the refence to is the Powermanager and the BluetoothAdapter.. but they are system objects :s! How can they be dead?